Send "heartbeat" ping messages JS
I am 100% new to programing, and I am having a hard time online finding out how to do this. All I find are very old questions (like this one from 12 years ago) saying that this was not possible then. What about now?
I have access to a server. From what I was told, the server will respond automatically to pings.
In my website I have a websocket:
const loc = window.location;
const protocol = loc.protocol === "https:" ? "wss:" : "ws:";
const ws = new WebSocket(protocol + "//" + loc.host + loc.pathname + "/../ws");

// Then, to send messages to the server I do:
ws.send(JSON.stringify(jsonMessage));

The server is running behind a reverse proxy that is closing the connection after 5 minutes without a message. I need to somehow send a ping every X seconds to both keep the connection alive, and check on the client side that the server is still up.
I assume this is very common, but I am having a hard time doing this. I appreciate any help in the right direction.
If it matters, the server is using axum websocket and documentation says it "automatically" responds to pings.

You haven't shown us any of your server code, so only you know what a "heartbeat" or "ping" are in this context. Are you asking how to run Javascript every x seconds? Because that is something you should Google for, not ask Stackoverflow.

It is not common at all.  Connections fail for all kinds of reasons.  The SOLUTION is to write code that can survive disconnects by reconnecting, not by trying to hack the system.

@AndyRay Sorry, I am just learning, so I thought this was standard terminology. I am using ping and heartbeat as described in this context.

This question is similar to: Sending websocket ping/pong frame from browser. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you could provide how your server receives a message and responds to a ping then only anyone would be able to help. In my opinion if the server is simply receiving a ws message then a simple setTimout would work. And also are you trying to do a health check for your server using your frontend if so then please re phrase your question ?

@AndyRay As I mentioned, old questions like the one you linked don't really have an answer. It just says that it was not possible (12 years ago). I am asking if it is still the case.

it is still the case

This I believe would be achieved the easiest using the setInterval function provided by js. This could be done with something like the following:
const interval = setInterval(pingServer, pingInterval);  

In the example above the pingServer would be whatever function you would like to use to ping the server and the pingInterval which is whatever you want the delay between pings to be in milliseconds.
Along with this we set it to the variable interval, so we can reference this later when we need to eventually close the connection. Our variable interval stores the intervalId which we need to use the function clearInterval also provided by js.
Example use:
clearInterval(interval);

Let me know if anything needs clarification or if I didn't answer your question fully!

Thanks, this allows me to keep the connection alive by sending something periodically. But how do I send a ping (as described here, it mentions something about "control frame", "opcode", etc.)? For these ping messages, the server will reply with a pong (that I can use to check that the server is still up), instead of just periodic messages to prevent the reverse proxy closing the connection. Maybe I am misunderstanding all these ping/pong stuff.
